# How to handle UV seams in generated textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I want to create textures for an existing model.

I use material nodes in blender to do so, but I cannot get the UV seams to line up correctly.

Examples:

[image: UV mapping]
[image: Object/generated mapping]

It's either a visible shift at the seam or it just looks warped from one side.

Is there a way to use UV mapping and line up the textures correctly?
I cannot change the UVs, because the textures wont fit to the in game model (at least I think it is that way)

Things I tried:

Seperating XYZ so I can replace the distorted part with a generative Texture rotated by 90° (didn't work)

Comment: Generally, when using generated textures, you would set them up, then "bake" them into an image texture which can be used as a material for a game model. This is why generated textures are usually seen connected to "Generated" (as opposed to UV) texture coordinates. Moreover, even if you use UV coordinates, it is unlikely blender's shader system is compatible with that of whatever game engine you plan to use, so you would have to bake anyway.

Comment: For generated textures, using unseamed coordinates (like object, generated, or geometry/position) is a better idea.  As mentioned above, you can then bake to UV textures as desired.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I do know how to bake the textures, my Issue is, that I am not able to get the seam to line up correctly

Comment: @Nathan my problem with generated coordinates is, that it gets warped on the side (see the second picture)

Comment: I'm not sure there's any magic solution for your texture, maybe make it as good as possible, bake the diffuse, use the result in an Image Texture, try to fix the seam playing with the UVs and/or the image

Comment: If it is possible to bake textures from one UV to another that would solve my problem :/